# StAX end element tag with "<element attributes.. />" rather than whole end tag </element>

Tags: java, stax

I am streaming XML document, the following is the sample code.

```
final XMLOutputFactory xof =  XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final XMLStreamWriter xtw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(os);
xtw.writeStartDocument("utf-8", "1.0");
xtw.writeStartElement("Buddy");
xtw.writeAttribute("Name", "AB");
xtw.writeAttribute("Age", "25");
xtw.writeAttribute("petName", "XX");
xtw.writeEndElement();
xtw.close();
```

This produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Buddy Name="AB" Age="25" petName="XX"></Buddy>
```

How can I make StAX write

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Buddy Name="AB" Age="25" petName="XX"/>
```

i.e. the end tag "" is not required, it should end the tag as soon as the attributes  are written. Any ideas?

**INTENTION**: To minimise the number of bytes sent over the network. Roughly 15k messages per second. Hence its worth saving some bytes per message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `writeEmptyElement(...)` for this:

```
xtw.writeStartDocument("utf-8", "1.0");
xtw.writeEmptyElement("Buddy");
xtw.writeAttribute("Name", "AB");
xtw.writeAttribute("Age", "25");
xtw.writeAttribute("petName", "XX");
xtw.writeEndDocument();
```

No `writeEndElement()` is needed for empty elements.